# Como evito que el texto siga una linea recta html

Tags: html

Al introducir texto, este sigue una línea recta y sigue infinitamente haciendo que aparezca un scroll para verlo completamente, y quisiera que en vez de que siga recto, se haga un salto de línea, pero sin usar la etiqueta br, con css quizá.

Para el diseño estoy usando materialize.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dentro de la etiqueta dodne tienes contenido ese texto aplicale el siguiente estilo:

```
<style>
    p{
      word-wrap: break-word;
    }
  </style>
```

Ayudará a romper la línea y partirla en 2 para que no se te desborde, yo por ejemplo se la aplique a un párrafo que tengo lleno de texto y que se me esta desbordando

Comment: Funcionó, gracias.

Comment: Lo haré, pero tengo que esperar 6 minutos, no sé por qué, pero bueno.

Answer (score 1):

Materialize es un framework CSS que es responsivo, es decir, que permite redimensionar todos los elementos que renderea para que su visualización sea correcto.

Para su caso, y sin saber como construyó el texto, este puede ir dentro del un div con la clase `flow-text`, un ejemplo sería así:

```
<p class="flow-text">El texto de su documento</p>
```

Con esto debería corregir el problema que tiene